# Proving Linear Dependency of A based of $ (SpA)^\perp = \{(a,a-b,b-c,a)\mid a,b,c \in R\} $

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have this question for homework:

> Let A be a set of 2 vectors in $R^4$
>
> Given that: $ (SpA)^\perp = \{ (a,a-b,b-c,a)\mid a,b,c \in R \} $
>
> Prove that A is Linearly Dependent.

I think I need to use the facet that the orthogonal complement is equal to the solutions of the linear system $Ax=0$. However I am not sure how (maybe it's not the way at all).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not *group*, *set*! **Hint:** What is the dimension of $(\text{span}(A))^T?$ How do you relate the dimension of $\mathbb R^4$ with the dimensions of $\text{span}(A)$ and $(\text{span}(A))^T$?

Comment: Hmm, Thanks for the hint, but I find myself unable to answer those questions

Comment: The answer your got is exactly what my hint points towards. Alternatively you can recall that $\left((\text{span}(A))^T\right)^T=\text{span}(A)$ and you can explicitly find the LHS of this equality. **Edit:** Type \$\mathbb R\$ to get $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that

$\dim (SpA)+\dim((SpA)^\perp)=\dim(\mathbb{R^4})=4$

and $\dim((SpA)^\perp)=3 $ so $\dim (SpA)=1$.

if the 2 vectors in A are not linearly dependent so $\dim((SpA)^\perp)=2 $.
so we got that the vectors in A are linearly dependent.

Comment: The command `\dim` renders as $\dim$.